# Identifying 'Concepts' for a system HCI

Tags: user-interface, human-computer-interface

I'm designing an interface based on data gathered from users. It is for a website which allows you get advice on choosing a restaurant. I'm strictly following a textbook which says you must identify the 'concepts' within the system for effective design but doesn't give clues as to how to do so- I was just wondering what types of thing would be considered a concept. Another textbook describes an ambulance dispatch service and identifies two of the concepts as being 'the incident' & 'the phone call' to the ambulance dispatch. I can't seem to effectively transpose this idea for my task. Can anyone recommend anything based on experience? Or even a definition for a 'concept' regarding systems in HCI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't read your textbook obviously, but i think it's important to think what data goes into the site and what comes out (will be displayed). For this example i'm thinking about concepts like "restaurant", "user review", "restaurant rating", "cuisine". But it all depends on how your website works ofcourse.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying. At this stage, I haven't thought what exactly is going into the website. I'm trying to identify concepts to aid in the decision of the type components to be included. That's the way this book has it mapped out anyway to identify concepts prior to thinking about design. I'm interested to get your opinions though...Would you identify concept whilst designing then?

Comment: If you are talking about design, i assume you mean graphical design. Before making a graphical design you should figure out what the website exactly does. In your case you already know it's about restaurants. So try to decide what information about restaurants you want.

Comment: Ok great I think I get it. So 'location' would also be considered as a concept - if for example m site had a search by location aspect...